# Reachability in Swift 3

Tags: swift, reachability

I am new at this and can not seem to figure out how to use `NSURLSession dataTaskWithResult:completion handler` replacing `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronusRequest(request as URLRequest, returning: &response`
in the following code. The latter has been depreciated.

```
public class Reachability {
    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
        var status:Bool = false

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

        var response:URLResponse?

        do {
            let _ = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning: &response) as NSData?
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                status = true
            }
        }
        return status
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution with a completion handler

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request) { (data, response, error) in
      if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
        completion(true)
      } else {
        completion(false)
      }
    }.resume()
}
```

And to call

```
Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork { success in
  if success {
    // google is up
  } else {
    // google is down.
  }
}
```

Comment: This is FABULOUS. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Now, I can't figure out how to make the call. This is what I have:

if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
           
            self.gettingInfo = self.model.getInfo()
            
        } else {
            
            //Get local questions from the qizz model
            self.questions = self.model.getLocalQuestions()
        }

Comment: The method works asynchronously. The result is returned **in** the closure. I updated the answer.